# Using managed identities to invoke a http triggered function app inside another function app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-managed-identity

Need some help being pointed in the right direction. Struggling to find an appropriate resource.
I've got a Http triggered function within a function app that I need to invoke from another function app. How can I authenticate this call using system managed identities?

The two function apps are .Net 6 isolated functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ManagedIdentityCredential from Azure.Identity Nuget package to get an access token for the other Function app.

Note that you need an app registration for the Function that you will call as you can't acquire an access token for the other Function's Managed Identity.
You can acquire the access token using scope `app-registration-client-id/.default`.

Note you must implement authorization in the other Function to properly check the token claims.
For example, you can check that the caller is the other Managed Identity.
Optionally, you can define an app permission/app role that you assign to the Managed Identity.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any code resources that show how to get the access token and implement the authorization? Also is it either implement authorization or define an app permission/app role or must you always implement the authorization?

Comment: Well you need some sort of authorization always. You can either match the caller id or you can check their permissions (or both I guess). The main reason you need to do that especially here is that Azure AD is quite happy to give any application in your tenant an access token to any other application. The token just won't contain any permissions, but you probably don't want to allow any app to call the Function.

Comment: This shows at least how to use the Azure.Identity library somewhat: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#get-a-token-using-the-azure-identity-client-library. They are acquiring an access token for Key Vault but the principle is the same (just replace the scope with one for your app).

Comment: Awesome. If you find anything to do the authorization as well that would be great :D

Comment: I found this article useful when using OAuth2 and managed identities to protect APIs via app registration https://medium.com/medialesson/role-based-authorization-in-azure-functions-with-azure-ad-and-app-roles-b1fed5714c91